# consume COM library from C# to rust

Tags: rust, com, windows-rs

## Question

I want to rewrite my project from C# to rust.
But I stuck in Segmentation Fault situation.
I think I misunderstood something, or meet crate limitation, hope for some help.

### Rust Code

- find interface UUID
  [regedit capture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14807780/218402049-4b2f21f6-4996-48cc-ae91-e10d2b31676b.png)
- find CLSID
  [regedit capture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14807780/218403295-293d6dbf-e54f-4da0-80d8-17d9b11f5328.png)
- other id (I'm not sure shall we need it)
  [regedit capture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14807780/218402661-94627f8d-911d-42c2-aef1-27988698a572.png)

```
use windows::core::{GUID, HRESULT, IUnknown, IUnknown_Vtbl, interface};
use windows::Win32::System::Com::{
    COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED, 
    CLSCTX_ALL,
    CoInitializeEx,
    CoCreateInstance};

// define interface
#[interface("288EFDEC-3CF0-4F6C-8473-4E4CD47A93C7")]
unsafe trait Inhicshisx: IUnknown {
    fn VPNGetRandomX(&self) -> HRESULT;
}

fn run() -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {
    unsafe {
        // 2F5AECD5-B5CD-41E1-8265-E2F6AA4548CB
        const CLSID: GUID = GUID {
            data1: 0x2F5AECD5,
            data2: 0xB5CD,
            data3: 0x41E1,
            data4: [0x82, 0x65, 0xE2, 0xF6, 0xAA, 0x45, 0x48, 0xCB],
        };
        
        // initialize runtime
        CoInitializeEx(Some(ptr::null_mut() as *mut c_void), COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)?;
        
        // create COM object
        let hisx: Inhicshisx = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID, None, CLSCTX_ALL)?;
        
        // call object function
        let value = hisx.VPNGetRandomX();
    }
    
    Ok(())
}
```

### C# Part

- add a reference
  [regedit capture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14807780/218400999-d3816353-a141-41a4-aa6e-867b3c6d812e.png)
- call function

```
using CSHISXLib;
string MyStr0;
CSHISXLib.Inhicshisx CSHISXLibObj = new CSHISXLib.nhicshisx();
MyStr0 = CSHISXLibObj.VPNGetRandomX();
Console.WriteLine(MyStr0);
```

- It works.

### Update information

According to @IInspectable help, I can generate interface by *oleview.exe* tool.

- generated interface

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(288EFDEC-3CF0-4F6C-8473-4E4CD47A93C7),
  helpstring("Inhicshisx Interface"),
  dual,
  oleautomation
]
interface Inhicshisx : IDispatch {
    [id(0x00000001), helpstring("method VPNGetRandomX")]
    HRESULT VPNGetRandomX([out, retval] BSTR* strRandom);
    [id(0x00000002), helpstring("method VPNH_SignX")]
    HRESULT VPNH_SignX(
                    [in] BSTR strRandom, 
                    [in, optional, defaultvalue("")] BSTR strCardType, 
                    [in, optional, defaultvalue("")] BSTR strServiceType, 
                    [out, retval] BSTR* strRet);
}
```

- Rust code change

```
use windows::core::BSTR;

#[interface("288EFDEC-3CF0-4F6C-8473-4E4CD47A93C7")]
unsafe trait Inhicshisx: IDispatch {
    fn VPNGetRandomX(&self) -> BSTR;
    fn VPNH_SignX(&self, *mut BSTR, *mut BSTR, *mut BSTR) -> BSTR;
}
```

But it still cause **Segmentation Fault**, hope some advice

Comment: The signature for `VPNGetRandomX` looks wrong. In the C# code it appears to be returning a string (of some kind), whereas the Rust version is declared as returning an `HRESULT` only. Please show the IDL description of the `Inhicshisx` interface.

Comment: @IInspectable: My (limited) understanding of COM interfaces is that they generally returns `HRESULT` for all functions, and the actual return value is returned with an output parameter, something like a `BSTR*`. The C# marshall will convert that to an actual return type plus an exception, but I don't think the Rust one will do that.

Comment: @IInspectable Actually, this com library dll file is come from third party team. I'm new to windows programming, is there tool can I extract IDL from dll file? Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to discover the shape of interfaces given just a COM server DLL. However, you appear to have a type library (.tlb) as well. A TLB is a machine-readable description of interfaces. You can load it into [oleview.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer) and have it display the interface descriptions. Or, let MSVC generate C++ header files using an [`#import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp) directive.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you very much! oleview.exe helped me take a big step forward. Now, I can generate COM library interface.

Comment: There is no automatic parameter translation happening here. You'll have to faithfully represent the ABI contract. The signature for `VPNGetRandomX` would probably need to look something like `fn VPNGetRandomX(&self, *mut BSTR) -> HRESULT`.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank a lot! It work! I misunderstand the interface. Really thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Thank for @IInspectable advice.

> **Segmentation Fault** caused by wrong interface.

### Find the COM interface

> you can use [oleview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer) to display for COM library interface. In my case, the interface like this.

```
interface Inhicshisx : IDispatch {
    [id(0x00000001), helpstring("method VPNGetRandomX")]
    HRESULT VPNGetRandomX([out, retval] BSTR* strRandom);
    [id(0x00000002), helpstring("method VPNH_SignX")]
    HRESULT VPNH_SignX(
                    [in] BSTR strRandom, 
                    [in, optional, defaultvalue("")] BSTR strCardType, 
                    [in, optional, defaultvalue("")] BSTR strServiceType, 
                    [out, retval] BSTR* strRet);
}
```

### Declare interface in Rust

```
#[interface("288EFDEC-3CF0-4F6C-8473-4E4CD47A93C7")]
unsafe trait Inhicshisx: IDispatch {
    fn VPNGetRandomX(&self, random: *mut BSTR) -> HRESULT;
    fn VPNH_SignX(&self, random: BSTR, card_type: BSTR, service_type: BSTR, sign: *mut BSTR) -> HRESULT;
}
```